# No Rails gem specified - Bamboo stack, rails 3.0.20, we cannot deploy from two days ago

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I cannot deploy.

```
! Heroku Bamboo does not include any Rails gems by default.
! You'll need to declare it in either .gems or Gemfile.
! See http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/gems for details on specifying gems.

! Push failed: no Rails gem specified.
! If the problem persists, see http://help.heroku.com and provide Request ID 730a25d4-d2f2-43a7-899b-aa2ab071b4f7.
```

Some days ago I did it perfectly.

I have a Gemfile working well. I really don't know what is happening.

Tell me what you need to know in order to shed some light on this. We are really confused.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Post the contents of your Gemfile.  It should have a rails gem version specified.

Comment: I've had always `gem 'rails', '3.0.20'` there. This monday I did a deploy without problem. This is weird because now I'm not able to do it. These are the contents of the file: https://gist.github.com/josal/7179134. Thanks @Winfield

Comment: Finally, talking with heroku support, there is an encoding problem with the project... They provided a custom buildpack so that I can deploy the new code, while they fix the problem and update the default buildpack.